# Dynamic subtitle with gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, dynamic, gganimate

I made a dynamic heatmap using historic football result with gganimate. It shows how many goals were scored each year by home and away teams on aggregate. For the title I have the Seasons, which changes with the frames (title = 'Season: {closest_state}'). But for the subtitle I would like to display the most common result each year (I have the "Most_Common_Result_Home" and the "Most_Common_Result_Away" columns for this. I tried different approaches so far, but nothing seems to work.

The closest I get to the soulution was this: subtitle = paste("Most Common Result:", dataset$Most_Common_Result_Home, "-", most_common_results$Most_Common_Result_Away), but it doesnt change dynamically.

You can see the script below. The "hg" is the home goals, "ag" is the away goals (0,1,2,3,4,5+) and the count100roll is the occurance of different results (hg-ag) for a hundred matches (rolling average).

I would be glad if someone could help to find a solution. Thank you!

```
plot <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = factor(hg), y = factor(ag), fill = count100roll)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = custom_palette) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(0,1,2,3,4,5), labels = c("0","1","2","3","4","5+"))+
  scale_y_discrete(breaks = c(0,1,2,3,4,5), labels = c("0","1","2","3","4","5+"))+
  guides(fill=guide_colorbar(ticks.colour = NA))+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill= NA, color = "white", size = 5),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill= "black"), 
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(family = "A", size = 15, face = 'bold', color = "white"),
        axis.title = element_text(family = "A", size = 18, color = "white"),
        plot.title = element_text(family = "A", size = 20, face = 'bold', hjust = 0.5, color = "white"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(family = "A", size = 12, face = 'bold', hjust = 0.5, color = "white"),
        legend.text = element_text(family = "A",size = 12, color = "white"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'bottom',
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(0.4, "cm"),
        axis.ticks = element_line(color = "white"))+
  transition_states(states = Season, transition_length = 0, state_length = 1) +
  labs(x = "Home Team Goals", y = "Away Team Goals", title = 'Season: {closest_state}') +
  enter_fade() +
  exit_fade()
```

The closest I get to the soulution was this:
`subtitle = paste("Most Common Result:", dataset$Most_Common_Result_Home, "-", most_common_results$Most_Common_Result_Away), but it doesnt change dynamically.`

I also tried creating a custon label and then using geom text:
`dataset$Custom_Label <- paste("Season: {closest_state}", "- Most Common Result:", Most_Common_Result_Home, "-", Most_Common_Result_Away)`

`geom_text(aes(x = max(hg), y = max(ag) / 2, label = Custom_Label), hjust = 1, vjust = 1, size = 4)`

I alsot tried it with annotate.

Comment: Perhaps [Displaying data value in subtitle of gganimate plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65392490/displaying-data-value-in-subtitle-of-gganimate-plot-r/65393114#65393114) helps to answer your question. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared via `dput()`.